# Laravel blade not escaping HTML

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel 5.2 and for some reason the blade standard tags `{{...}}` are not escaping HTML as wrote in the documentation.

When I tries to write for example `{{ HTML::tag('span','hello') }}` I get the correct HTML and see `hello` in my browser. The I get same results if I write `{!! HTML::tag('span','hello') !!}`.

So why the `{{...}}` tags does not escaping the HTML tags, as they should?

Comment: Does the same happen if you write the HTML directly in the blade tags? I.E. `{{ "<span>Hello</span>" }}` What package are you using with the HTML facade?

Comment: No, when I write `{{ "<span>Hello</span>" }}` it's escape the html, and I am using `laravelcollective/html`

Comment: What is the `tage` method? I can't find it in any of the `laravelcollective/html` documentation or when searching the github repository. Are you using the version of the package thats compatible with Laravel 5.2? `"laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"`

Comment: So is the code posted in your question a mistype?

Comment: Oops, typing mistake :).. And yes the version is `5.2.*`

Comment: And try this: `{!! "<p>".HTML::tag('span','<div>hello</div>')."</p>" !!}`
What is output? (I dont have L5 to try it myself). It can be in it, that HTML::tag is running after {!! !!}

Comment: The output is the correct html. I can see only `hello` in my browser. If I replace the tags with `{{...}}` it escaping the html. Maybe the functions in `Html` and `Form` classes are special, and they not escaped by blend for some reason... But still in the documentation it seems that they should be in `{!!...!!}` tags..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `{{...}}` for variable printing.

and `{!!...!!}` this for normal html. you can just write plain html without braces and it will show correctly.